# Perl - Assign an array to another variable

Tags: arrays, hash, perl

I'm trying to assign an array to a value in my hash as follows:

```
$authors->[$x]->{'books'} = @books;
```

`$authors` is an *array of hashes* that contains his/her first name, last name, date of birth, etc. And now I'm creating a `books` key where I want to assign an array of books. However, when I try to print it afterwords, it's just printing the size of the array, as if I'm doing `$value = scalar @books`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10):

Array elements and hash values are scalars, so when you are nesting arrays and hashes, you must use references. Just as `$authors->[$x]` is not a hash but a reference to a hash, you must set `$authors->[$x]->{'books'}` to a reference to the array.

```
$authors->[$x]->{'books'} = \@books; # reference the original array
$authors->[$x]->{'books'} = [@books]; # reference a copy
```

You would then access elements of the array using something like

```
$authors->[$x]->{'books'}->[0]
```

which can be abbreviated

```
$authors->[$x]{books}[0]
```

or access the whole array as

```
@{$authors->[$x]{books}}
```

Your original attempt

```
$authors->[$x]->{'books'} = @books;
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
$authors->[$x]->{'books'} = scalar @books;
```

because the left operand of the `=` operator is a hash value, which is a scalar, so the right operand is evaluated in scalar context to provide something that can be assigned there.

P.S.

On rereading this answer I realized it may be confusing to say "a hash value is a scalar" because of the possible interpretation of "hash value" as meaning "the value of a hash variable" i.e. "the whole hash". What I mean when I write "hash value" is an item that is *stored in* a hash as a value (as opposed to a key).

Comment: Thanks! That worked. What is the difference between "reference the original array" method versus "reference a copy" method? And what is meant by "reference"? Is this the same as in C?

Comment: @Ricky `[ @books ]` (you can call `[ ]`the anonymous array constructor) takes `@books` and makes a copy that can be held as a reference "anonymously".  With `\@books` you are referring to the original array. This makes a difference if you change any of the elements - *i.e*.does it change the copy or the reference **and** the original? See [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [`perldoc perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html). There's many a handy guide/blog post comparing [perl references and  C pointers](http://www.teaser.fr/~amajorel/psgfcp/) :-)

Comment: @Ricky  Fire up the [**`re.pl`**](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::REPL) or the debugger and try: `my @test1 = qw/ q w e r t y / ; my $test2 = \@test1 ; my $test3 = [ @test1 ]`.  Then `pop` an element from each of those `$test2` and `$test3` array references and see how it affects `@test1`.

Answer (score 2):

While the first awnser is absolutely right,
as an alternative, you could also fo this:

```
push @{$authors->[$x]->{'books'}}, @books;
```

Then `$authors->[$x]->{'books'}` will be an Array that contains a copy of all 
the elements from `@books`.
This might be more "foolproof" then working with references, as
mentioned above.

Comment: yes, your are right, its the same as `$authors->[$x]->{'books'} = [@books]; # reference a copy`. My bad, should have looked better at the other awnser.